# How to append a conditional command to a command that is already running?

Tags: macos, terminal

Let's say I have three commands that I run like this:

> `a && b && c`

This will run b after a completes, and `c` after `b` completes.

What if I did this:

> `a && b`

While this is running, I want to append c as a conditional command. Can it be done?

Comment: Is this Linux or MacOSX? If in doubt tag it with the used shell.

Comment: I'm using OSX, but it should be the same as Linux.

Comment: No, MacOSX is Unix and Linux is Linux. Additionally there's a ton of different shells out there for Linux, which might provide different solutions.

Comment: @Bobby There are also different shells on OSX, but given no contrary information, `bash` is a good assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

- `a && b`
- press `ctrl-Z` to suspend the current pipeline
- `bg 1` to run it in background
- `wait %1 && c`

`wait` waits for the specified job to complete, and returns its result status, so that the above behaves like `a && b && c` would have.

You can also define an alias or function, eg `alias bgwait='bg 1 && wait %1'`. Then, after pressing `ctrl-Z`, all you have to type is `bgwait && c`.
Supporting multiple jobs is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the last operation is stored in `$?`. 0 means no errors occurred, anything else is a problem.

You can e.g. use it like this

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then c; fi
```

Make it a function or similar in your `.bash_profile` and you can run it a bit more comfortably.

Comment: So how would I type this command if a program is already running? Would I open up another terminal?

Comment: @OSXJedi you just type it in (assuming your currently running program has no input). It'll get executed after your program quits, not different than typing it afterwards, except that you don't need to wait for `b` before leaving the machine.

Answer (score -2):

For NT, you can type your new command and hit ENTER while a current command is running.

So for example,

c:\blah>dir /s

where blah is big enough that you'll have time to type while stuff scrolls onto the screen.

now all this stuff scrolls on the screen

and while it is appearing, type mem

then after dir /s is complete, mem will run.

Comment: The question was about _conditional_ commands (`&&`).

Comment: And it was also not about Windows.

Comment: Hang on. When I answered it, he had still not said what OS.  So I took it as a general question and gave an answer of what'd work for NT. And secondly.  if you think about it, my answer is true of "conditional commands".  It's exactly it. If he runs a && b, and he wants it to act as if he'd done a && b && c, but he didn't put the && c in there. He can do just as i've said. And it works conditionally in the same manner. Does it not?

Comment: he may have meant conditional in terms of the command returning something true/false. but in that instance perhaps he'd see if it's true/false while it's running (which is when he plans to run the command anyway), and then he'd decide whether to run the command. I think he might've just meant running one commmand after another.

Comment: @barlop: But the tags were also there. Though, a little bit confusing but excluding Windows.

Comment: @Bobby Did the tags mention any particular OS? I notice you asked what OS. My reply was before his answer.

Comment: @barlop: Yes, it was tagged `Linux` and `MacOS`, as you can see in the revision history. I asked for clarification, because they can exclude each other if it comes to possible solutions.